# Spring batch: processing multiple record at once

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch and as normally used I have reader , processor and writer .

I have 2 questions

1>
Reader queries all 200 records (total record size in table is 200 and I have given pagesize=200 )and thus it gets me all 200 records, and in processor we want list of all these record because we have to compare each record with other 199 records to group them in different tiers .
Thus I am thinking if we can get that list in processing step , I can manipulate them .how should I approach .

2>
In processing stage I need some master data from database depending on which all input records will be processed .i m thinking of injection of data source in processing bean and fetch all master table data and process all records. Is it good approach or please suggest otherwise .

```
<job id="sampleJob">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="itemReader" processor="processor" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="20"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>
```

And the processor is

```
@Override
public User process(Object item) throws Exception {
    // transform item to user
    return user;
}
```

And I want something like

```
public List<User> process(List<Object> item) throws Exception {
    // transform item to user
    return user;
}
```

I found some post [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/111650-itemprocessor-receiving-one-item-returning-more-than-one) but they say to get the list in writer .But i dont like to process anything in writer, because that kills the defination of writer and processor. Is there any configuration to get the list inside this process method.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `ItemProcessor` receives whatever you return from the `ItemReader`, you need your `ItemReader` to return the `List`.  That `List` is really the "item" you're processing.  There is an example of this in the Spring Batch Samples.  The `AggregateItemReader` reads all the items from a delegate `ItemReader` and returns them as a single list.  You can take a look at it on Github here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java

Comment: Thanks . But this class is more of fetching records from file . Do we have similar class to fetch from database . As we can't override read method it's not possible to extend job paging item reader .

Comment: The same idea applies and you don't override the read method on the pagingitemreader...you wrap that reader with one that reads from the delegate until the input is exhausted and then return that list as a single item.

Comment: I created a delegate aggregate item reader , which seems working , I get a list of records in processing stage . But then it loops sith null values . I don't need to write any mapper and reader class , can u please confirm.

Comment: I don't understand "But then it loops sith null values ."

Comment: Holder.isExhausted || holder.getRecords()>0{ return holder.getRecords();}

Comment: That second condition I added which seems very risky to me and my brain not working now , somehow I feel it will fail some case

Comment: I think I am good with that second condition because that would be the page size and only after list is populated within while loop it comes out and just expected once per each read .. Thanks a lot . Will take sometime to look at this more deep  .

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks ... now i can process multiple records inside processor , but how should I return just one item to persist (using jdbcbatchitermwriter ) can you suggest something to return one record from processor and so that I can control by giving size of commit-interval.

Comment: I tried delegate the writer and it works, so I wrapped writer within customized writer (extending jdbcbatchitermwriter ) and used property of jdbcbatchitermwriter and working fine... But is there anyway I can return just one record from processor..

Comment: is AggregateItemReader part of spring batch artifact?

Comment: @ChandreshMishra It is not. There is a sample of how to do one in our samples. If you search for it, you'll find it.

Comment: How do I know whether specific record is header/footer in a custom ItemReader when reading records from DB by pageSize each?

Comment: How do I implement isHeader isFooter on the aggregate ? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline/AggregateItemReader.java#L81