# How to process List of items in Spring batch using Chunk based processing| Bulk processing items in Chunk

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to implement a Spring batch job where in order to process a record , it require 2-3 db calls which is slowing down the processing of records(size is 1 million).If I go with chunk based processing it would process each record separately and would be slow in performance. So, I need to process 1000 records in one go as bulk processing which would reduce the db calls and performance would increase. But my question is If I implement Tasklet then I would lose the functionality of restartability and retrial/skip features too and if implemented using AggregateInputReader I am not sure what would be the impact on restartability and transaction handling.
As per the below thread AggregateReader should work but not sure its impact on transaction handling and restartability in case of failure:

[Spring batch: processing multiple record at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049613/spring-batch-processing-multiple-record-at-onc)

Comment: `I am trying to implement a Spring batch job where in order to process a record , it require 2-3 db calls which is slowing down the processing of records(size is 1 million)`: Can you describe the algorithm you designed to solve this problem without referring to Spring Batch?  `I need to process 1000 records in one go as bulk processing which would reduce the db calls and performance would increase`: Let's assume you have a list of 1000 records, how would do the `2-3 db calls` for each of them at once (ie in bulk as you mentioned)?

Comment: The processing would be like it will pick a collection of n records( lets say 1000 records) from db and do the transformation/enrichment for each of the 'n' records. For doing the enrichment/transformation it requires 2-3 db calls. So , in order to improve the performance I was planning to hit the db 2-3 times for all 1000 records i.e there will be 2-3 queries running sequentially, that will fetch the enrichment data for all the 1000 records and that will be loaded in memory and used to enrich all the 1000 records

Comment: The queries can be like select * from table_name where id in (ids of all 1000 records)

Comment: ok, I still don't see how will you consume the result of such queries, but if you manage to do it, you can use a `ItemWriteListener` to enrich items in bulk as mentioned in my answer. If it were up to me and the processing of one record is independent from other records, I would start with a multi-threaded step or a partitioned step. But the precise answer to your question is using a `ItemWriteListener#beforeWrite` as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Can we use AggregateItemreader and pass list of items to processor with chunk size of 1. The only drawback i see here is that the framework will consider the list of items as one read /write and in case of restart the items already processed could be processed again.Please correct me if I am missing anything

Comment: That's not a good idea IMO because you would need to handle a list of lists in your listener, writer, etc. Give it a try and you will see that it can become convoluted very quickly (especially with generics). You should leverage the chunking already implemented by the  `ChunkOrientedTasklet` and use a regular reader where an item is a single item (which is more natural to think about compared to thinking about a list of items as an aggregate item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first extension point in the chunk-oriented processing model that gives you access to the list of items to be written is the `ItemWriteListener#beforeWrite(List items)`. So if you do not want to enrich items one at a time in an `ItemProcessor`, you can use that listener to do the enrichment for the entire chunk at once.