# Can We Process Whole Chunk Together in Spring Batch Processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a scenario where I have million records in employee staging table, I need to enrich the value and store it in employee final table. Now I am using chunk processing with chunk size of 10,000.

In processor where I have to do enriching I want to collect all employee-id for that chunk and do 1 API call per chunk and enrich value. Instead of million call for million records.

I am observing that reader I am using right now which is extending RepositoryItemReader is not returning List as I am using JPA I am using RepositoryItemReader.
So processing is happening 1 time per item even after chunk size as 10,000.

Can we get the whole List from reader and do processing on it?
Or is there any other approach, cause I cant really make 1 call per record.

```
public class EmployeeStagingReader extends RepositoryItemReader<EmployeeStaging>{
     public EmployeeStagingReader(EmployeeStagingRepository repo){
       super();
       this.setRepository(repo);
       this.setMethodName("findAll");
       final Map<String,Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
       sorts.put("ID",Sort.Direction.ASC)
       this.setSort(sorts);
  }
}


public class EmployeeProcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<EmployeeStaging>, List<EmployeeFinal>> {
  
        //Want to Perform transformation  of stagingemployee list of records and return employeefinal list of records

    }
}


@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<List<EmployeeStaging>, List<EmployeeFinal>>chunk(1000)
                .reader(EmployeeStagingReader())
                .processor(EmployeeProcessor())
                .writer(EmployeeFinalWriter())
                .build();
}
```

Comment: Another approach would be to do the enrichment in your ItemWriter.

Comment: Okay. Agreed as it's taking input as list of items wrt chunk size.

Comment: check this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049613/spring-batch-processing-multiple-record-at-once

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

1. Create a Tasklet step before data persisting step which is chunk based one.
2. So in this Tasklet step, group employee-ids and make API calls and update employee-ids in staging table itself. So, you can manage to reduce API calls.
3. In last step, just read data and write using chuck based approach. No more required processor too.